# TF run session: operation precedence

Tags: python, tensorflow

I do not understand why when running initialisation of a Variable as well as the assign method in one run call, the value does not get assigned? Is it something to do with parallel execution, or is there no operation precedence? TF [session management](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/client/session_management) does not explain it.

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
W = tf.Variable(10)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([W.initializer, W.assign(20)])
    print W.eval()  # 
 >> returns 10, but I would expect 20


#running it separately:
    sess.run(W.initializer)
    sess.run(W.assign(20))
    print W.eval()
 >> returns 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this happens because in the first place `W.initializer` is executed after `W.assign(20)` overwriting it's value to its initial state.

As you can see, changing the order in the second example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
W = tf.Variable(10)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(W.assign(20))
    sess.run(W.initializer)
    print W.eval()
```

gives you the same results as you got in the first one.

Comment: Ok, I see, but isn't it illogical? Why can I assign to a variable if it is not initialized yet? Then does it mean that sess.run([..,...]) runs commands from the right?

Comment: @JanSila whether it is logical or not is not for me to decide. Why do you need to change the value you just assigned? No the order in sess.run does not matter, what matters is where they stand in DAG.

Comment: @JanSila, TensorFlow runs every object declared as in a map/graph/network point. So you need to initiate the network under a session first. Then you can do the actual work.